# Is there any type of performance hit using Flask-Bootstrap?

Tags: python, performance, flask, flask-bootstrap

From what I can tell, Flask-Bootstrap mainly just provides a base template that you use to make additional templates.

The Flask-Bootstrap template resides in my site-packages folder.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't just copy that base.html out of the site-packages folder, and put it into my templates folder and customize as my own base? Then I wouldn't even need to use Flask-Bootstrap, right?

Or, am I wrong in thinking that all it's doing is providing that base template?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are thinking right. You don't need to put it to the site-package instead keep it in your template folder and customize as you want. Flask-bootstrap base template defines macros and blocks but you can do the time without flask-bootstrap. Blocks and macros comes from jinja2 so you can create a base html template.

Let's say your base.html has follows content:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

#index.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1> index page </h>
{% endblock %}
```

And if you add bootstrap css to your base then your all other pages will support bootstrap.

Note: The developers created flask-bootstrap to help others development process, but you can create your own.